# YAML.load_file Cannot Read ENV Variables Correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, yaml

I have set up a secondary database YAML file as this:

```rb
# config/remote_database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: 'cexplorer'
  username: <%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_IP'] %>
  port: 5432
```

this YAML file is read from an initializer that creates a variable to use for `establish_connection`:

```rb
# config/initializers/remote_database.rb

REMOTE_DB = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "remote_database.yml"))[Rails.env.to_s]
```

When I check with a `byebug` how the REMOTE_DB looks I see that the ENV variables are read with the placeholder rather than the variable itself even though the variable are available.

```rb
# app/models/remote_record.rb

class RemoteRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  byebug
  establish_connection REMOTE_DB
end
```

```
[1, 5] in /Users/sergio/Documents/github/swan-to-db-sync-backend/app/models/db_sync_record.rb
   1: class RemoteRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
   2:   byebug
=> 3:   establish_connection DB_SYNC_DB
   4:   # REMOTE_DB is defined in `config/initializers/db_sync_database.rb`
   5: end
(byebug) REMOTE_DB
{"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"cexplorer", "username"=>"<%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>", "password"=>"<%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>", "host"=>"<%= ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_IP'] %>", "port"=>"5432"}
(byebug) ENV['HOST_PG_DATABASE_USERNAME']
"postgres"
(byebug)
```

How do I get the actual ENV variables vaues inside REMOTE_DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure `YAML` doesn't know anything about the ERB syntax and doesn't interpret it automatically when loading a file.

This is confusing because in Ruby on Rails this seems to work in all YAML config files. But it only works, because Ruby does some magic internally.

When you want to load a YAML file and interpret ERB in that file on the fly then you need to change your YAML loading code to something like this:

```
file = File.read(Rails.root.join("config", "remote_database.yml"))
yaml = ERB.new(file).result

REMOTE_DB = YAML.load(yaml)[Rails.env.to_s]
```

Comment: While this does answer the question its a very clear case of needlessly reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby YAML module does not pass files through ERB. Thats actually a Rails specific feature of [`ActionSupport::ConfigurationFile`.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/03516a924e71db7e065c8fb31c1d37af9b7c34ce/activesupport/lib/active_support/configuration_file.rb#L9)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ActiveSupport
  # Reads a YAML configuration file, evaluating any ERB, then
  # parsing the resulting YAML.
  #
  # Warns in case of YAML confusing characters, like invisible
  # non-breaking spaces.
  class ConfigurationFile # :nodoc:
    class FormatError < StandardError; end

    def initialize(content_path)
      @content_path = content_path.to_s
      @content = read content_path
    end

    def self.parse(content_path, **options)
      new(content_path).parse(**options)
    end

    def parse(context: nil, **options)
      YAML.load(render(context), **options) || {}
    rescue Psych::SyntaxError => error
      raise "YAML syntax error occurred while parsing #{@content_path}. " \
            "Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. " \
            "Error: #{error.message}"
    end

    private
      def read(content_path)
        require "yaml"
        require "erb"

        File.read(content_path).tap do |content|
          if content.include?("\u00A0")
            warn "#{content_path} contains invisible non-breaking spaces, you may want to remove those"
          end
        end
      end

      def render(context)
        erb = ERB.new(@content).tap { |e| e.filename = @content_path }
        context ? erb.result(context) : erb.result
      end
  end
end
```

So you can parse a configuration file with:

```
@config = ActiveSupport::ConfigurationFile.parse(path_to_file)
```

ActiveRecord actually has a few more tricks up its sleeve where it merges the YAML configuration with `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`.

**However you don't actually need this in the first place.** In Rails 6+ you can actually [define multiple databases per environment](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html):

```
development:
  primary:
    database: my_development_database
    adapter: mysql
  remote:
    database: my_primary_database
    host: somehost
    adapter: mysql
```

And in any previous version you can either create more environments such as a staging environment or use `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` to [supplement/override the YAML configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database).

Comment: multiple database as per doc did not work for me because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541744/multiple-databases-with-rails-not-working-for-remote-database)

Comment: You can still just use an additional root level key in your single `database.env` file and then fetch that configuration with `Rails.configuration.database_configuration[:foo]` where `:foo` is whatever you choose to call your root key.